# overcome the lack of polymorphism in C

Tags: c, polymorphism

I'm working on a project that ***strictly requires*** to realize two set of functions in C with same signature that can be used from a sigle .c test file. one set is for a data structure, the other one for a different and incompatible data structure.
Since in C there is no polymorphism is not possible to call a function that has two implementation with same signature in two different headers (.h) files and taking for granted that the call will be referred to the right implementation of the function that is actually capable of managing the right data structure.
Ok I know it seems impossible and contradictory but..that is it...
*I have to merge two generic items that can be list or dynamic array*
Update: 
on List.h (dynamicArray is in another .h)

```
    typedef struct Node{
  void *data;
  struct Node *next, *prevNode;
} Node;

//typedef struct declaration List
typedef struct List {
  struct Node *top, *bot, *prev;
  int size;
} List;



//in the dynamicarray.h file:
typedef struct dynamicArray{
  void **array;
  size_t size;
  size_t capacity;
}dynArray;



//in the dynamicarray.h file:
void* merge(void *element1,void *element2, int parameters){
  void * returner;

  if (parameters==ARRAY) {
    returner= Array_Merge(element1,element2); // expected to receive two arrays
  }
  else {
    returner= List_Merge(element1,element2); // expected to reveice two lists
  }

  return returner;
}
```

Do you have any suggestion to accomplish this request?
Thanks.

Comment: I would rather examine this ***strict requirement*** for sanity.

Comment: Use a `union`...

Comment: The functions could take a `void*` pointer to a `struct` and an `enum` telling how to proceed. The standard function `qsort` manages to be type-agnostic.

Comment: "same signature" and "different ... data structure",  Post example code and/or detail to the seemingly contradictory statements.

Comment: What sort of work will the two sets of functions be performing?

Comment: one is lists and the other one is dynamic arrays. Unfortuntely you cannot for example pass a parameter that says to the unique function "ok I'm giving you a List" because at some point after you checked that inside that function, you will need to use proper functions of both lists or dynamic arrays depending of what you checked from a passed integer for example... this is impossible because you have declare List and dynamicarray in the same .h ...

Comment: What does the declaration for your list look like?  What does the declaration for your dynamic array look like?  (I'm guessing both declarations look exactly the same?)

Comment: no. there are some different fields, not comparable

Comment: @J.G. More things are possible than you may think, yet seeing some example structures and or code would go a long way in helping to achieve your goal.  IOWs, rather than only describe the data, post the structures

Comment: OK.  But you did say the two methods having the same name would also have the same parameter signature, correct?

Comment: I'll leave on top everything, like the fields of the structs- so you can work on that

Comment: You didn't include your method definitions, or what kind of operations you expect to perform on your structs.

Comment: But normally, if you're defining data structures such as lists and trees, you would also declare functions that operate on those structures in your `.h` files, and implementations of those functions in the corresponding `.c` files.  Your structs are different enough that they're probably going to have their own implementations.

Comment: And now what I'm thinking you really want is compile-time polymorphism (i.e. function overloading), which C does not provide out of the box, not without some serious workarounds.  [See here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism#C) for a potential solution.

Comment: Finally, if your requirement specifications genuinely stipulate language features that C does not provide (they shouldn't; the kinds of features you're describing are *implementation details*), then perhaps the answer is to use a programming language that *does* have these features, like C++?

Comment: What functions do you want to use on these data types?

Comment: Have you considered the `_Generic` construct?

Comment: *I have to merge two generic items that can be list or dynamic array*

Comment: You're going in the wrong direction with `void **array;` — I recommend using a `union` hack to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass both, a pointer to your function and some handler function to the test, along with argument(s). In 'c' `void *` can be use in place of any pointer. Something like the following might work for you:

```
int mytest(void*(*function)(void *), int(*handler)(void *), void *arg) {
    if (handler(function(arg)))
       return OK;
    return FAIL;
}
```

So, you just need to have separate handler functions for arrays and lists and pass them to the test function along with other params.

**Answering your last comment**

I can imagine some scheme as the following.

```
List list1;
dyArray array1;

MergedList outList;
MergedArray outArray;
...

void *getNextArrayElement(dynArray *array){...}
void *getNextListElement(List *list){...}

int mergeAsList(void* el, void *list){   
   if (el == NULL)
      return 0;
   ListMember *mmb = malloc(sizeof(ListMember));
   mmb->el = el;
   mmb->next = ((MergeList*)list)->head;
   (MergeList*)mergeList->head = mmb;
    return 1;
}

int mergeAsArray(void *el, void *array) {
    if (el == NULL)
      return 0;
    if (((MergeArray *)array)->index) >= MAX)
       return 0;
    ((MergeArray *)array)[((MergeArray *)array)->index++] = el;
    return 1;
} 
int mergeAsSortedArray(void *el, void *array){...}
...

test(getNextArrayEelement, mergeAsList, &arraty1, &outList);
test(getNextListEelement, mergeAsList, &list1, &outArray);
...

int test (void *(get*)(void*), 
          int (merge*)(void *m1, void *result), 
          void *in, 
          void *out) {
   void *el = get(in);
   int res = merge(el, out);
   return res;
}
```

Comment: in my case I have to merge two generic items that can be list or dynamic array. so there is a single merge function that can receive both data types

Comment: sure, you just need 2 or 3 handler functions, 1) get element from item 1, 2) get element from item 2, 3) create a new element as an array or a list. This what you do in a polymorphic world in any case, just encapsulate them in 3 classes.

Comment: I posted the current merge function on top of the page, how can I modify the merge to make it work fine according to your method?

Answer (score 0):

Function pointers are the means in which you accomplish this.

Function pointers are what you would use if, for example, you wanted to pass a function to a sort function that told the sort function how to compare two adjacent members.  Such a comparison function allows you to provide a generalized sort function that will work on a collection of any `struct`, since you can change out the comparison function to accommodate any struct.

Consider the following sort code:

```
typedef struct node{
  void* item;
  struct node* next;
} Node;

// Just an ordinary bubble sort
void sort(Node *start, bool greaterThan(void* a, void* b)) 
{ 
    int swapped, i; 
    Node *ptr1; 
    Node *lptr = NULL; 

    /* Checking for empty list */
    if (start == NULL) 
        return; 

    do
    { 
        swapped = 0; 
        ptr1 = start; 

        while (ptr1->next != lptr) 
        { 
            if (greaterThan(ptr1->item, ptr1->next->item))
            { 
                swap(ptr1, ptr1->next); 
                swapped = 1; 
            } 
            ptr1 = ptr1->next; 
        } 
        lptr = ptr1; 
    } 
    while (swapped); 
}

// Swap function used above
void swap(Node *a, Node *b) 
{ 
    void* temp = a->item; 
    a->item = b->item; 
    b->item = temp; 
}
```

To use it, we just need to define a payload to put into `Node* item`  and a sort function to tell it how to order the items:

```
typedef struct {
   int  book_id;
   char title[50];
   char author[50];
   char subject[100];
   char ISBN[13];
} Book;

// Comparison function.
bool bookGreaterThan(void* left, void* right)
{
  Book* a = (Book*)left;
  Book* b = (Book*)right;

  return strcmp(a->title, b->title) > 0;
}
```

Finally, you would sort your list like so:

```
// Pass a pointer to the first node in your list, and a function pointer to your comparer.
sort(pointerToMyList, bookGreaterThan);
```

A complete example can be found [here](https://repl.it/@robertwharvey/Sorting-with-Comparator-Function-in-C).

See also [Is it possible to achieve runtime polymorphism in C?](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-achieve-runtime-polymorphism-in-C)

Comment: I added more code about the actual merge function, I like the answer of Serge. If you have any idea how to modify it...

Comment: @J.G. It would be better if you learn how this works and modify it yourself.  You're the one that is going to have to maintain it.